# Trying to update a table using contenteditable td and storing data using php into sql database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, contenteditable, updating

I'm echoing information from a database using a while loop in php and would then like to be able to directly edit the td and then press a button to save the changes to the database. I've looked online and found some code that uses JQuery and Ajax to do this but I can't seem to get it to work for me. I'm very new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated on this!

I've tried a few different methods of doing this and this seemed the most straight forward way, I've tried to use an update query but am not familiar enough with the different languages to know if I've linked them all correctly.

This is the html - I've got all the db connections and everything in previously -

```
    <div class="users_table">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>House ID</th>
    <th>House Name</th>
    <th>Motto</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>



    <?php

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM houses");
    $STH->execute(array());

     while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
       $house_id = $row->house_id;
      $house_name = $row->house_name;
      $house_motto = $row->house_motto;
      $house_colour = $row->house_colour;

    ?>
    <tr>
    <form method="post" action="">
          <td><?php echo $house_id; ?></td>
      <section id="editable" contenteditable="true">
        <td contenteditable><?php echo $house_name; ?></td>
        <td contenteditable><?php echo $house_motto; ?></td>
      </section>
        <td><input type="button" id="save" value="Save Changes"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear Change" /></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="house_id" value="<?php echo $house_id; ?>">
    </form>
      </tr>
          <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>




    </div>
```

This is the JS file -

```
          $(document).ready(function(){

          //  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

          $('.update_form').click(function() {
          $('.slide_down').slideToggle('slow');
          });

          alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

          var editable = document.getElementById('editable');

          addEvent(editable, 'blur', function () {
            // lame that we're hooking the blur event
            localStorage.setItem('contenteditable', this.innerHTML);
            document.designMode = 'off';
          });

          addEvent(editable, 'focus', function () {
            document.designMode = 'on';
          });

          addEvent(document.getElementById('clear'), 'click', function () {
            localStorage.clear();
            window.location = window.location; // refresh
          });

          if (localStorage.getItem('contenteditable')) {
            editable.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('contenteditable');
          }

           $(document).ready(function(argument) {
           $('#save').click(function(){
           // Get edit field value
           $edit = $('#editable');
           $.ajax({
           url: 'get.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {data: $edit},
           datatype: 'html',
           success: function(rsp){
           alert(rsp);
           }
           });
           });
           });




          });
```

This is the get.php file -

```
    //get.php
    <?php
    $editData = $_POST['data'];

    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['data']))
    {

        // get variables from the URL/form
        $house_id = $_POST['house_id'];
        $house_name = htmlentities($_POST['house_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $house_motto = htmlentities($_POST['house_motto'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $house_colour = htmlentities($_POST['house_colour'], ENT_QUOTES);

        // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE users SET house_name = ?, house_motto = ?, house_colour = ? WHERE house_id = ?");
        $STH->execute(array($house_name,$house_motto,$house_colour,$house_id));

      }

    echo $editData;
    ?>
```

I know the jquery file is linked as the alert shows up but am not sure why it's not inserting the updated data into the db.

Comment: `This is the JS file -` u copied php file twice

Comment: Sorry have edited and copied the right one now - any help would be great!

Comment: If you haven't done so already, one thing to check is if get.php is being hit when you click the save button.  Have you brought up the developer tools for the browser (F12) and gone to the Network tab to see if you get any errors?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: data in get.php on line 8

Is the error I'm getting on the get.php

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:14)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: OK, so it sounds like your get.php is crashing.  The reason is because it's looking for the data property and it's not finding it because it's not being sent.  I'm wondering if it's because in your jquery ajax you have for your data property an object with a data property and so things are getting confused.  In that object in your data property, I would give it another name and try again. Also, to respond to  the author of a comment on your post, you have to use the author's name like @DougF in your comment so it notifies the author and they can respond more quickly.